# Knockout auto-complete

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout js in my SharePoint 2010 project with a SP Services library. I'm trying to implement auto-complete function for one of the field. Here is my code:

This how looks my input field:

```
<input id="newTask" title="task" data-bind="value: newTask" placeholder="Add new task" /> 
<button data-bind="click: addTask" class="btn">
```

This is my ViewModel.js:

```
(function() {
function Task(data) {
    this.Tasks = ko.observable(data.Tasks);
    /*other fields*/
}
function TaskListViewModel() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);    
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var taskList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Tasks");     
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.taskInformation = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTask = ko.observable();
    /*other fields*/
    self.addTask = function() {
        self.taskInformation.push(new Task(
            {
                Tasks: this.newTask(),
                /*other fields*/
                }));
            self.newTask("");
    };

var taskListViewModel;

$(document).ready(function() { 
    EnsureScriptFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() { 
    taskListViewModel = new TaskListViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(taskListViewModel ); 
    }); 
});
})();
```

This script from my View.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#newTask').on('input propertychange paste', function (e) {
        var val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        viewModel.newTask(val);
    });

    // Init
    viewModel = new taskListViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("parent-container"));

    $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({ 
        sourceList: "Bidders",
        sourceColumn: "Title",
        columnName: "task",
        ignoreCase: true,
        numChars: 3,
        slideDownSpeed: 1000,
        debug: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Auto-complete works, however newly added task takes only characters which were typed. E.g: I type Mic (auto complete gives me option for Microsoft), when I select this option and click add, it takes only Mic.

Comment: `SPServices.SPAutocomplete` looks like some kind of (DOM-manipulating) jQuery plugin? If it is, consider creating a custom binding handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made this on my input element

```
 <input data-bind="textInput: task, valueUpdate:'blur'"/>
```

and it works, only in IE11. My clients use ie, so I'm satisfied with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually trigger the input to tell knockout that the input as been manipulated.

```
<input id="newTask" title="task" data-bind="value: newTask" placeholder="Add new task" /> 

$('#newTask').on('input propertychange paste', function (e) {
   var val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
   viewModel.newTask(val);
});

// Init
viewModel = new TaskList();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel , document.getElementById("parent-container"));
```

Further Edit

```
var _taskList;
$(document).ready(function() { 
    EnsureScriptFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {
        _taskList = new TaskListViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(_taskList);
    });
    $('#newTask').on('input propertychange paste', function (e) {
        var val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        _taskList.newTask(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tyler can you please advise how can I access my ViewModel? I've tried this: TaskListViewModel.newTask(val); But I getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: TaskListViewModel is not defined

Comment: See Edit - TaskListViewModel should be a global variable for that page.

Comment: The problem is that, I have it in a separate js file called ViewModel. And it's organized like this, see updated quest post. And I cannot figure it out how make it global (I've tried to move TaskViewModel outside of the function, but started get some error).

Comment: var taskListViewModel; -- global variable

$(document).ready(function() { 
    EnsureScriptFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {
        taskListViewModel = new TaskListViewModel()
        ko.applyBindings(taskListViewModel );
    });
});

Comment: In my view I'm still getting undefined error, see updated post above.

Comment: create a demo of your code, ill be able to resolve it. have you made viewModel a global variable like requested above as i dont see this in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much Tyler, I've resolved my issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `value` binding, the observable value is only updated in the view model on blur. If you're using KO 3.2+, you should use the `textInput` binding, which updates the observable immediately.

If you're not, you should consider upgrading. I've found that using jQuery events, as [tyler_mitchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2720927/tyler-mitchell) suggested, isn't as reliable as I'd hoped. But if you're not upgrading, that's the way to go.